# Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, stack-memory

I'm reading a textbook which shows assembly code based on C code:

**C code:**

```
void echo()
{
   char buf[8];
   otherFunction(buf);
}
```

**assembly code:**

```
echo:
   subq $24, %rsp      //Allocate 24 bytes on stack, but why allocate 24 instead of 8 bytes?
   movq %rsp, %rdi     //Compute buf as %rsp
   call otherFunction
```

I don't understand why stack pointer `%rsp` is decremented by 24 bytes. I only assign 8 bytes' buffer as `char buf[8];`, and there no callee saved registers to push on stack, shouldn't the instruction be

```
subq $8, %rsp
```

Comment: I think stack frame sizes are rounded up to 32 byte alignment

Comment: @Barmar: No, gcc only maintains 16-byte alignment, the minimum required by x86-64 ABIs.  If you did `alignas(32) buf[8]`, you'd see extra code to over-align the stack.

Answer (score 13):

**Allocating an extra 16 bytes of stack space is a GCC missed optimization that pops up occasionally**.  I don't know why it happens, but it's reproducible with GCC10.1 `-O3`.  Clang doesn't do it, it just reserves 8 bytes (with a dummy `push`).  Example on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgA7KQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OrrLyinQMBMzEBH56BsaxmAo%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%2BUq%2BtyyWiJdpOi4ZFUXRTFY2ldMvhZCcWW4QZgGQZBBgtNlOEGCBcEIEgyQpK1Bk0HU9UcfC1kMJoiOpJ16VIMZmCwJwLlIJl3jWNlDAATm4HhnEFHk1n4rihFRMVSDrd4FQlXFUVleVFVo1UNQgJAfRNRxyEodTSKcFDO3NbYjOtW17UoOxYxdWh3Vzb1tT9eggxDWMIyjGMw3wBMcmTVNJQzLMcy6L18zkWN%2BzLYg3QrbpJWrWt62tOhGBYGM2wEK0DO7SQhBLQcWJHMdJ2nWc4gXCBTC/Ew1D/EorWPEJfDvAI6uCMcaqcK0rzHG9UialdH1KhIXzqTdap/Xr/H66RhvCc9QNaYDWzAtFxSg1EYLghDBmQAy0O2Nl9u2LCcKIYhyMI4iNLO8lKSo9QaOVOiGKYyhlvEyTpLWmUZAUpU6UZEB2M4ni%2BIE9jhNEroZ0gsNpQe/7IcMVbYbkxTHpaZNiC8ZRuCAA%3D), where `-fno-stack-protector -fno-pie` is the default, unlike GCC in many GNU/Linux distros.

Even `int buf;` / `foo(&buf)` results in over-allocation.

My wild guess is that there's something GCC doesn't optimize away until *after* it's already decided it needs more than 8 bytes of space (and thus needs 24).  Hopefully this good MCVE will let GCC devs find an fix that bug, if it's easily fixable.

Feel free to report this as a GCC `missed-optimization` bug (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/); I looked recently but didn't find an existing one.

---

You're correct that allocating 8 bytes would be enough for `char buf[8]` *and* re-align RSP by 16 before the `call`, as required by the x86-64 System V ABI ([Why does System V / AMD64 ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001)).

GCC is *not* trying to maintain 32-byte stack alignment or anything.  The default for `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is the minimum allowed by the ABI, `4` (2^4 = 16).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the stack must be 16 byte aligned for function calls but I have no clue as to why 24 bytes were allocated and not only 16.

There are some questions about this on SO already. [Why does GCC 6 assume data is 16-byte aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271584/why-does-gcc-6-assume-data-is-16-byte-aligned)

and on GCCs bugzilla
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40838

Comment: That seems to depend on the optimization: with -O0 there's a `push rbp` and a `sub rsp, 16`, however with -O3 it is `sub rsp, 24` instead and there is no push. Also, the size does indeed increase in increments of 16 bytes (24, 40, 56, ...)

Comment: Yes, x86-64 System V requires 16-byte alignment before a call. [Why does System V / AMD64 ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001).  The GCC bug you linked is about 32-bit mode.  The x86-64 System V ABI has *always* required 16-byte stack alignment, there was no breaking change (like there was for i386 System V, probably introduced by accident; see my comment on the bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40838#c91).