# Can anybody explain what does this function do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
do_something(int):
   push rbp
   mov rbp, rsp
   push rbx
   sub rsp, 24
   mov DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
   cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 1
   jg .L2
   mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
   jmp .L3
.L2:
   mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
   sub eax, 1
   mov edi, eax
   call do_something(int)
   mov ebx, eax
   mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
   sub eax, 2
   mov edi, eax
   call do_something(int)
   add eax, ebx
.L3:
   add rsp, 24
   pop rbx
   pop rbp
   ret
```

Comment: Everything in the code is hidden 100% of the code is calling another functions and offsets you havent provided no anyone can help you

Comment: @coderx64: `call do_something(int)` is calling *the same* function; the problem with this question is just lack of effort / attempt.  This is pretty clearly un-optimized `g++` output copy/pasted from https://godbolt.org/.  Changing the demangled `do_something(int)` to a valid asm symbol name like `do_something`, you could write a caller, and assemble this and run it so you could single-step.  It is a self-contained recursive function.

Comment: @PeterCordes but there alot of [rbp-20] which we dont know what it is.

Comment: @coderx64: Note the `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp` stack-frame setup, then `mov [rbp-20], edi` to dump the incoming integer arg to the stack.  Accessing locals relative to the frame pointer (and spill/reload between every C statement) is 100% standard for un-optimized code ("debug" builds, like `gcc -O0`, the default for gcc/clang.)  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)

Comment: Ok thanks for info. it was just confusing to me because im not so much working with stack-frame setup

Comment: This question will help nobody who stumbles upon it.
"Can somebody explain what this does" is not even a question, so it does not provide value for the community. Just yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It is an unoptimised recursive function in 64bit SystemV calling convention with one integer argument which returns integer value. It internally uses `RBX` plus a 4-byte (DWORD) local variable at `[rbp-20]`.

Called with negative argument, say **-1**, it returns `RAX=0x00000000_FFFFFFFF`.
Called with zero argument it returns 0.
Going thru it step by step it gives

```
do_something(0)=0;
do_something(1)=1;
do_something(2)=1;
do_something(3)=2;
do_something(4)=3;
do_something(5)=5;
do_something(6)=8;
do_something(7)=13;
...
```

Generally, for positive number **n** this function returns the sum of its two predecessors: **do_somenging(n)=do_something(n-1)+do_something(n-2)**

Comment: It's not a 24-byte local variable, that's was a misleading unhelpful description so I fixed it for you.  The extra 16 bytes GCC reserves but doesn't use (beyond the 8 below the saved RBX needed for alignment to follow the ABI) are just a missed optimization.  [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009070)

Comment: @PeterCordes yup wrong name. sorry to spoil

Comment: @phuclv: Deleted my comment, too, so future readers will have to recognize the sequence from the numbers.