# Over allocation of space in virtual studio

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, stack-frame

I am doing this course on x86-64 architecture and we are using virtual studio for that purpose, whether it's debugging or anything. So we have been given a code segment which is as follows:

```c
int func() {
    long long i = 0xf01dab1ef007ba11;
    long long j = 0x0b57ac1e5;
    return i+j;
}

int main() {
    return func();
}
```

Now when I used the debugger this is the assembly instruction
[image: assembly listing of previous code]
I got and here is the stack diagram
[image: stack diagram]
for the same. Now if we see in the stack diagram at the address `00000000'0014FDD0` there is an extra 8 byte of allocations. I found the reason in the Microsoft docs and it states that **The stack will always be maintained 16-byte aligned, except within the prolog (for example, after the return the address is pushed)... There are few exceptions though.**

- Now  here is another code segment

```c
int func() {
    long long i = 0xf01dab1ef007ba11;
    long long j = 0x0b57ac1e5;
    long long k = 0x57abbadabad00;
    return i + j;
}

int main() {
    return func();
}
```

And again this is the assembly instruction
[image: assembly listing of previous code]
and here is the stack diagram
[image: stack diagram]
for it. Now I understand that why there is an extra 8 bytes of allocation at the address `00000000'0014FED0`, which is to keep the stack 16-byte aligned.

**But what I don't understand is why there is an extra allocation at the address `000000000'014FDC8? Is it necessary?**

Comment: No, it's not necessary, you can eliminate that 16 byte padding or even the whole stack frame. I suspect it is only because optimization is disabled.

Comment: Related: GCC has similar missed-optimization bugs, even with optimization enabled: [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009070)