# frame stack size in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I am reading an introductory computer design book. The book explains the inner workings using MIPS, is very information dense and expects the reader to connect the dots.

This is the c code:

```
main ()
{
 printf (“The factorial of 10 is %d\n”, fact (10));
}
int fact (int n)
{
 if (n < 1)
 return (1);
 else
 return (n * fact (n - 1));
}
```

And this is the first few lines of a mips assembly:

```
 .text
 .globl main
main:
 subu $sp,$sp,32 # Stack frame is 32 bytes long
 sw $ra,20($sp) # Save return address
 sw $fp,16($sp) # Save old frame pointer
 addiu $fp,$sp,28 # Set up frame pointer
```

The author states the following:

> Upon entry, the routine main creates its stack frame and saves the two
> calleesaved registers it will modify: $fp and $ra. The frame is
> larger than required for these two register because the calling
> convention requires the minimum size of a stack frame to be 24 bytes.
> This minimum frame can hold four argument registers ($a0–$a3) and the
> return address $ra, padded to a double-word boundary (24 bytes). Since
> main also needs to save $fp, its stack frame must be two words larger
> (remember: the stack pointer is kept doubleword aligned).

My understanding is that positions 0,4,8 and 12 of the stack frame are reserved for $a0-$a3 registers. That is why the old `$fp` is placed at 16 and `$ra` is stored at 20(up to 23). That is 24 bytes total. 24 is doubleword aligned (double word aligned means that it is address%8 == 0 and 24%8 == 0, right?). Why is the stack 32 bytes if 24 matches the criterium of double word alignment? Also why does the frame pointer not start at old `$sp` address, but at 4 bytes later? I feel like I am missing some additional information.

Comment: It is achieving double word alignment.

Comment: @ErikEidt the double word alignment is also achieved with 24 bytes. No need for 32.

Comment: It's possible that's real GCC output (GCC5.4 `-O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer`  https://godbolt.org/z/41Mb1xh1n also allocates 32 bytes, but lays out the saved stuff differently.) And GCC's over-allocation of stack space bug happens here, too: [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009070)